# How to hide column in the table based on the number of days in the selected month?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view, there is a datepicker for filters according to the selected month and one table. The table has 32 columns, where column 1-32 is the date. What I want to ask is how to hide column 29,30,31 when I choose February(Because February only has dates until 28)?, and also if I choose April, column 31 will disappear.
below is my code, thanks.

```
private AttendecencesViewModel LoadDataAttendence(AttendecencesViewModel model)
{
   queryJoin = db.AttendenceVs.ToList();
   if (model.SearchPayrollMonth != null)
   {
        queryJoin = queryJoin.ToList().Where(x => x.PayrollMonth == model.SearchPayrollMonth);
   }
   foreach (AttendenceV attendenceV in queryJoin)
   { 
       AttendenceViewModel detail = new AttendenceViewModel();
       detail.EmployeeName = attendenceV.EmployeeName;
       detail.PresenceDay01 = attendenceV.PresenceDay01;
       detail.PresenceDay02 = attendenceV.PresenceDay02;
       detail.PresenceDay03 = attendenceV.PresenceDay03;
       attedenceViewModel.AttendenceDetails.Add(detail);
   }
   return attedenceViewModel;
}
public ActionResult Search(AttendecencesViewModel model)
{
   attedenceViewModel = LoadDataAttendence(model);
   return View("Index", attedenceViewModel);
}
```

View

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchMonth, new { @class = "form-control" })
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th> //I only made it until the 3rd,
      .
      .
      <th>31</th>
    </tr>
     @foreach (MyExercise.Data.ViewModel.AttendenceViewModel item in Model.AttendenceDetails)
     { 
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay01)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay02)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay03)</td>
             .
             .
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay31)</td>
        </tr>
     }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(<year>, <month>)` to obtain the number of the days in the specified year/month . Using this value you can hide/show extra columns:

```
@foreach (MyExercise.Data.ViewModel.AttendenceViewModel item in Model.AttendenceDetails)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay01)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay02)</td>
        @* ... *@
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay28)</td>
        @if (daysInMonth >= 29)
        {
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay29)</td>  
        }

        @if (daysInMonth >= 29)
        {
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresenceDay28)</td>
        }

        @* until 31...use the same idea in thead *@
    </tr>
}
```